# Disassembling raw MIPS binary, 'can't disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN'

Tags: linux, mips, disassembly, mips32, opcode

I tried disassemble raw MIPS binary with opcodes on Linux machine. I run command

```
$ mips-linux-gnu-objdump -D -b binary bootloader.bin

bootloader.bin:     file format binary

mips-linux-gnu-objdump: can't disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN!
```

how to solve this?

**Edit:** the answer is:

```
mips-linux-gnu-objdump -D -b binary -m mips bootloader.bin
```